# how to hide all posts under one category

Tags: archives, get-posts

Suppose I have a lot of posts under notices category. When I click on notices, it will display all posts one after another under the notices.Instead of displaying one post after another, how to hide this posts and display these post content in tabular form

Answer (score -1):

You need a plugin like this https://wordpress.org/plugins/the-post-grid/ to show the post in grid view.